# When did hanging emerge as a form of capital punishment?

Tags: ancient-history, law, death-penalty

As the title has it: when did [hanging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanging) emerge as a form of legal execution? The Wikipedia article (linked) has nothing to say about this. I've done the best I can with a search in [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=history+hanging++execution&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C39), but failed to spot treatments of this particular issue.

It's entirely possible it arose spontaneously in different cultures at different times. I'm interested in *primary source* documentary evidence for its earliest use, wherever that might be.

<sub>This question arises from a discussion of the [book of Esther](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/12924/2215) on Hermeneutics.SE.</sub>

Comment: this might come handy  http://www.deathpenaltyinfo.org/

Comment: Does it matter what legal authority authorized the hanging? Is hanging at the whim of an autocrat (governmental or in wartime) acceptable?  Or do you need merely judicial hanging?

Comment: Right after rope was invented?

Comment: @TylerDurden - Har! ;) Oddly enough, I think you'll find that isn't so, however.

Comment: I was going to add an answer saying the *Book of Esther*  mentions hanging, but I now see that you are already aware of that. Aside: As far as I can tell, punishment in ancient times was supposed to be cruel **and** unusual. Hanging is a rather benign sort of execution compared to some of the nastier corporal punishment techniques used in ancient times.

Comment: I checked the Law Code of Hammurabi (~1750 B.C.) since, to my knowledge, it contains the oldest codified judicial punishments in the world. Unfortunately, the text only states that perpetrators shall be "put to death" without actually specifying what form of capital punishment should be used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Book 22 of the Homeric Odyssey contains a rather graphic description of how Telemachus hanged his father’s unfaithful maidservants. The Odyssey is of course a work of fiction, but it is reasonable to see this passage as evidence for the use of hanging as a judicial punishment at that time. Current scholarship puts the Homeric poems between 750 and 600 BC.

Here is relevant passage in Butler's translation:

> Then when they had made the whole place quite clean and orderly, they
>   took the women out and hemmed them in the narrow space between the
>   wall of the domed room and that of the yard, so that they could not
>   get away: and Telemakhos said to the other two, "I shall not let these
>   women die a clean death, for they were insolent to me and my mother,
>   and used to sleep with the suitors."
>
> So saying he made a ship's cable fast to one of the bearing-posts that
>   supported the roof of the domed room, and secured it all around the
>   building, at a good height, lest any of the women's feet should touch
>   the ground; and as thrushes or doves beat against a net that has been
>   set for them in a thicket just as they were getting to their nest, and
>   a terrible fate awaits them, even so did the women have to put their
>   heads in nooses one after the other and die most miserably. Their feet
>   moved convulsively for a while, but not for very long.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I'm looking for. Very interesting, too, that the concept needs to be explained. The account gives the impression of  describing something unfamiliar.

Comment: There's a strong trend thinking that Homer was recounting oral accounts of events that actually happened (of course embellished and with some mysticism added for the audience), passed on over generations.

Comment: Current scholarship does *not* put the Homeric poems around 1200. Far from it. Current scholarship places the poems from 750 at the very earliest. Their final shape wasn't achieved a hundred years later.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer. There is actually no consensus about the date of the Homeric poems, or about their (single or multiple) authorship. But even if we put them in the 8th century I am not sure that there is any earlier reference to hanging. But I am open to suggestions.

Comment: There is absolutely consensus that the Homeric poems are no earlier than the eighth century. It might not be important to the question at hand, but it is an egregious error that shouldn't be in a top answer on a history site.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer. I have now altered my answer accordingly, but allow myself one parting shot: in the world of scholarship there is no "absolute consensus" about anything.

Comment: Of course not. Someone will always misinterpret the evidence. For example, I didn't write that there was absolute consensus, but that there absolutely was consensus. It's a nuance that shouldn't be glossed over. But maybe one person will dispute that, killing any chance of absolute consensus.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer Homeric poems very likely have their origin closer to 1200BC than 700BC, even if they weren't compiled until much later. I would not have edited the answer.

Comment: That is absolutely not true. Every bit of the Homeric poems comes from Dark Age Greece. Some pieces here and there might be as old as the Mycenaean Age, but the poems themselves are clearly late Dark Age/early Archaic poetry. Where are you possibly getting such an early date from?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to tag @Antrim. I seriously want to know where this information is coming from, because it's not from actual Classicists. I know  Lane Fox gets close, but even then it's a few hundred years after 1200, and the final composition (compilation in the common sense would be a mischaracterization) is closer to 740. All the standard books on Homer now say 750, starting with Leski (well before, but he's a good starting point!).

Comment: @C.M.Weimer I think you're using some strong language (_"Every bit of the Homeric poems comes from Dark Age Greece"_) to describe a very controversial topic even among scholars. We simply *do not know* how old the origin of each part of the Iliad is, although it seems likely that there's a mix of some very old stories/traditions with current ones (from the time of Homer, I mean). There's not enough evidence out there to make any definitive claims, in my opinion.

Comment: @Antrim As a scholar in the field, I can assure you that there is no controversy. I mean, if you want to say that some stories and traditions derive from earlier *sources*, then you're in good company. But that does not influence the date of the Iliad as a whole. Nagy, Janko, West all agree that the Iliad is at least ninth century. Nagy in fact would have it down to the sixth century, and perhaps even later in the Alexandrian period, though he's nigh alone there.

Comment: I think there must be some confusion here about what constitutes the Iliad. A story of a man gouging out the eye of a great giant might predate the Odyssey, but that doesn't mean the Odyssey should be dated to that time. We cannot date texts based on their sources.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer But how can you date the Iliad as a whole, if some of its verses may have remained static for hundreds of years? I'm not talking, or interested about the Iliad as a written book, but as a very old story. Is it that inconceivable that some of its verses are in fact primary sources from certain events?

Comment: @Antrim No "verses" come from 1200 BCE. That's simply linguistically impossible, considering that Mycenaean Greek was very different than the Ionic of the Iliad. At best certain formulas survive and are changed as the language changes.

Comment: Also, no, none of the verses are from the Trojan War itself. That's so fringe we literally label it pseudo-history.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer It doesn't have to be from 1200BC to to have remained static (or at least not have changed very much) for a long time before 800-700BC, right? Regarding the impossibility of any of it, I would be more cautious using those words with this topic. After all, the Iliad was an obvious work of fiction until it wasn't, Linear B wasn't an archaic form of Greek until it was, the Ahhiyawa had no relation to the Greeks until they were the Greeks, there was no war until the Tawagalawa letter said there was, all characters in the Iliad were fictional until we met Alaksandu and Etewoklewes...

Comment: @Antrim Your conflation of linguistic possibilities and historical possibilities is utterly contemptible. Besides, even though there was a historical Alaksandu, he does not make the Iliad less of a work of fiction. Even though there were wars at Troy that left it destroyed, it does not make the Iliad less of a work of fiction. Even if the the Ahhiyawa were Greeks (this is still debatable, though I think the connection is strong), that doesn't make the Iliad less of a work of fiction.

Comment: If someone were to write a story about George Bush going to war with Napoleon, it wouldn't be non-fiction because Bush and Napoleon were real entities. That's not how history is done.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer I just would rather keep a very open mind about topics which we can't know that much about because of the lack of evidence, just so in case we eventually do find that evidence, I don't look too stupid. The fact that you find the link between the Ahhiyawa and the Greeks still debatable is a good reminder of how reluctant academics (and people in general) can get regarding the acceptance of new theories that displace the ones they were taught.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer If someone were to write a story about George Bush going to war with Napoleon because of a terrorist attack in two very big towers in his main city, and went on to describe very specifically the geopolitical situation in 2000's US and 1800's Europe and the weapons and clothes each side wore, there'd definitely be a lot of history to be learned from it. 3000 years later I'd probably be arguing with an academic about the Busheid being or not completely full of s***, though.

Answer (score 2):

> The first recorded use of judicial hanging is in the Persian Empire approximately 2,500 years ago.[2](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/pages/frontline/shows/execution/readings/history.html) [New World Encyclopedia][1](http://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/hanging#cite_ref-1)

*(Aside: Note that the reference is to " Richard Clark"The process of judicial hanging", Capital Punishment U.K. Retrieved April 15, 2007.", which is not currently available; you might want to check the wayback machine)*

> Mosaic Law codified many capital crimes. In fact, there is evidence that Jews used many different techniques including stoning, hanging, beheading, crucifixion (copied from the Romans), throwing the criminal from a rock, and sawing asunder. [PBS](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/pages/frontline/shows/execution/readings/history.html)

PBS does not attach a date to "Mosaic Law"

> The Oxford English Dictionary states that hanging in this sense is "specifically to put to death by suspension by the neck", though it formerly also referred to crucifixion and death by impalement in which the body would remain "hanging". *[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanging)*

I suspect, based on the OED reference in wikipedia and on the two quotes listed that hanging goes back as far as human law, but the definition of hanging might not be precise.

---

*Update*
OP clarified that he is looking for primary source material.

[Eyewitness to history](http://www.eyewitnesstohistory.com/londonhanging.htm) cites

> This eyewitness account appears in: de Saussure, Cesar, A Foreign View of England in the Reigns of George I and George II (1902), reprinted in: Charles-Edwards, T. and B. Richardson, They Saw it Happen, An Anthology of Eyewitness's Accounts of Events in British History 1689-1897 (1958); Gatrell, V.I.C., The Hanging Tree: Execution and the English People 1770-1868 (1994).

[The Proceedings of the Old Bailey](http://www.oldbaileyonline.org/browse.jsp?ref=t17240812-52) documents the hanging of Jack Sheppard in 1724. This is the earliest primary source I've found so far.

Comment: Thanks for this - unfortunately, each of these makes assertions without citing any sources. The Wayback Machine does retain [a copy of the dead Wikipedia link](http://j.mp/1uixuaK) - it's no better, sadly. I believe these assertions are based on assumptions. I know of no "evidence" for hanging (as we understand it) in antiquity. There appears to be convergence on 10C A.D. for hanging in Britain, but can't even find documentary sources for that. Thanks for input, though.

Comment: I'm confused; I cited a source for each. Or are you stating that my sources are tertiary sources and that we don't have a primary source?

Comment: Yes - that's a good clarification. None of the sources you cite themselves give *any* evidence for their assertions. It's the *evidence* I'm after, which is why I phrased it as I did in my question.

Comment: @Davïd well, anyone who was there when the first hanging was performed is no doubt long dead and very likely didn't write about it. And any legal proceedings (if any, if it wasn't summary justice using whatever was available at the time which happened to be a tree and a rope) of those days is no doubt long lost as well...

Answer (score 1):

Primitive Norse and Germanic Cultures used ritual hanging to dedicate prisoners to the Gods, Odin or Wotan.

From Wikipedia: Odin

> Worship among the Germans
>
> Human sacrifices were very frequently offered to Odin, especially
>   prisoners taken in battle. The most common method of sacrifice was by
>   hanging the victim on a tree; and in the poem Hdvamfil the god himself
>   is represented as sacrificed in this way. The worship of Odin seems to
>   have prevailed chiefly, if not solely, in military circles, i.e. among
>   princely families and the retinues of warriors attached to them. It is
>   probable, however, that the worship of Odin was once common to most of
>   the Teutonic peoples.
>
> Owing to the very small amount of information which has come down to
>   us regarding the gods of ancient England and Germany, it cannot be
>   determined how far the character and adventures attributed to Odin in
>   Scandinavian mythology were known to other Teutonic peoples. From
>   Woden also most of the anglo-Saxon royal families traced their
>   descent.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - it would be wonderful if you could add a pointer to a primary source for it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_bog_bodies includes 3 people who were strangled or hanged, probably ritually. Borremose Man is dated to 700BCE.